# Error calling PHP through JQuery to overwrite HTML file

Tags: php, jquery, html, overwrite

I have a couple of arrays with string values:

```
var sites = [homehtml, evshtml, dhtml, registerhtml];
var names = ["pagehome.html", "pageevents.html", "pagedjs.html", "pageregister.html"];
```

So basically I've assigned each the values of a normal html file plus different things within body tags to differentiate:

```
var homehtml = "&lt;html&gt;&lt;head&gt;...";
```

Now, I'm using a for loop to call a JQuery function to overwrite html files I have online:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
    $.get("/cen3721/createsites.php", {site: sites[i], name: names[i]}, function(data){ alert(data)});          
}
```

The file `createsites.php`has the following:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['site']) && isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $site = $_GET['site'];
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        echo file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cen3721/' . $name, $site);
    }
?>
```

Where `cen3721` is a folder within my hosting space. This code has worked for me to overwrite a `.txt` file before (though I hadn't used variables as part of the file address. Is this wrong, or should I use another method to write to an HTML file? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: you never mention what specific error you are encountering

Comment: This is not a good idea. This will allow anyone to upload malicious scripts to your site. It would be better to define the lists and contents within PHP, and send only the names to the server.

Comment: What happens is that the files are not being overwritten, that's it. I don't get any javascript errors, and I'm not too sure about how to get to display PHP errors. This is for a class, so if it becomes too much I can always prepare the sites beforehand by saving the strings to txt files then converting them myself. Is this the right way to do it or not though?

Comment: approach is very strange. There are likely far more conventional approaches to do whatever it is your goal is

Comment: I want to display a string of text as an html file. so I'm using file_put_contents to overwrite a blank html file then open that to see if the string was written